ADFS login with error Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.InvalidRequestException: MSIS7042
i am add ADFS to identityserver

as the below code

services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddCookie()
.AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
{
    options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";
    options.Authority = "https://localhost:5000";
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
    options.UsePkce = false;
    options.Scope.Clear();
    options.Scope.Add("openid");
    options.Scope.Add("profile");
    options.Scope.Add("email");
    options.SaveTokens = true;
    options.MetadataAddress = "https://XXX/adfs/.well-known/openid-configuration";
    options.ClientId = "MY Client ID";
    options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/signin-oidc");
    options.TokenValidationParameters.SaveSigninToken = true;
    options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;

    options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
    {
        OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = context =>
        {
            context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("X-Redirect", "Redirecting to ADFS");
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        },
        OnTokenValidated = context =>
        {
            context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("X-TokenValidated", "Token validated successfully");
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        },
        OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
        {
            context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("X-AuthenticationFailed", "Authentication failed");
            context.Response.Redirect("/Home/Error?message=" + context.Exception.Message);
            context.HandleResponse();
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    };
});


the adfs screen login working fine and i can login, but after login the url redirect many times automatically, and throw this error
"OpenIdConnectProtocolException: Message contains error: 'server_error', error_description: 'MSIS9604%3a+An+error+occurred.+The+authorization+server+was+not+able+to+fulfill+the+request.', error_uri: 'error_uri is null'."


and in event viewer in server log this error

"Encountered error during OAuth authorization request.


Additional Data
Exception details:
Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.InvalidRequestException: MSIS7042: The same client browser session has made '6' requests in the last '7' seconds. Contact your administrator for details.
at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.PassiveProtocolHandler.UpdateLoopDetectionCookie(WrappedHttpListenerContext context)
at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.PassiveProtocolHandler.ProcessCommonCookiesInLastAuthenticationStage(ProtocolContext context)
at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.OAuth.OAuthAuthorization.OAuthAuthorizationProtocolHandler.SendAuthorizationResponse(OAuthAuthorizationRequestContext authContext, OAuthAuthorizationResponseMessage authResponse)"

There are a number of causes for this.
The most common is the missing trailing slash "/".
Or a mismatch between HTTP and HTTPS - I wrote this up here.
